# emit not working `router-outlet` to `app-component`

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am trying to communicate from one of `router-oulet` page to parent component as `app component` but not works.

here is my code :

home.component.ts:

```
import {Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  templateUrl:"home.component.html"
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() myEmiter = new EventEmitter<string>();

  ngOnInit(){}

  sendMessage(msg){
    this.myEmiter.emit(msg);
  }

}
```

In the app component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  @Input() msg:string = "default"; //msg not updating at all
}
```

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wcyfzh)

Comment: You can not communicate like that with `router-outlet`. You must either have a `child - parent` relationship with child selector or build a shared service of some kind to transfer the data.

Comment: can't we call the parent method at all?

Comment: Nope. Parent doesn't know WHICH child will be outleted, so Angular can not say if that `Input/Output` even exists on the child outleted.

Comment: @ritaj - thanking you. can you show me other quick and best approach to communicate then?

Comment: Sure, you should research "Angular2 shared services". This article I found the most helpful: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/